# The function call isn't working inside the React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the following, JSON data is fetching successfully from a parent component but the function `breakLine()` doesn't work when called inside the component, throwing the following error message.

> 'breakLine' is not defined  no-undef

***json.db***

```
{
 "studies": [
    {

      "text": [
         "first line here-=br=-second line here"
      ]
    }
}
```

***component code:***

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'   

class PortfolioPage extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {        
      resultText: []        
    }

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({         
      resultText: this.props.data.text
    })
  }    

  breakLine(text){
    text.replace("-=br=-", "\n");
  }

  render() {
    const { resultText } = this.state;       

    return (
      <div className="portfolio-pages">
        <p>
          {breakLine(resultText)}
        </p>
     </div>
     )
}

export default PortfolioPage
```

Comment: why is `text` an array?

Answer (score 0):

The `this.` is missing, you should call it with `this.breakLine(resultText)`.

Though your `resultText` is of type string[], so you will want to define the `breakLine` function as follows:

```
text.map(t => t.replace("-=br=-", "\n"))
```

if you want to have one line per array item, you could also do the following:

```
text.join("\n").replace("-=br=-", "\n").split("\n")
```

Comment: now there appeared another error message relative the body's function:
TypeError: text.replace is not a function

Comment: Because text is array not a string. Need to make changes accordingly.

Comment: but can you explain to me how to do it? wih toString function?

Comment: Why is `text` actually an array?

Comment: `text.map(t => t.replace("-=br=-", "\n"))`

Comment: Lorenz Henk because it is following a structure of a tutorial furthermore I will insert other things. But you can suggest better enhanced.

Comment: Rahul Raut your function didn't work, there isn't any error message but it didn't render nothing into the html

Comment: @claudiobitar  Modify your breakLine method as follows, which will render text.
Try this - 

breakLine(text){ text.forEach(function(val,index){ text[index]= text[index].replace("-=br=- ", "\n"); }) 
return text.join('\n ');
}

Comment: @Rahul Rault It didn't render into html. When I do console log on this line, 
 {this.breakLine(resultText)} there appears ["first line↵second line↵third line"]
0: "first line↵second line↵third line"

Comment: Are you sure you have a return statement in the breakLine method?

Answer (score 0):

Bind the function to current context and use *this* keyword:

```
breakLine = (text) => text.join(' ').replace("-=br=-", "\n");
// [...code...]
{this.breakLine(resultText)}
```

Comment: now there appeared another error message relative the body's function: TypeError: text.replace is not a function

Comment: log text argument to be sure it is a string

Comment: Because text is array not a string. Need to make changes accordingly.

Comment: text should be an array, as I can desume from your code, pick the string inside the array as replace its a method of the String prototype

Answer (score 0):

you need to bind this function to the context. try to use

```
class PortfolioPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    ...
    this.breakLine = this.breakLine.bind(this)
  }
```

or arrow style

```
breakLine = (text) => {...}
```